# Getting a TypeError when I try to import Sequelize from 'sequelize-typescript'

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

My application gives the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getQueryInterface' of undefined
```

when I try to `import {Sequelize} from 'sequelize-typescript'`

Below is a snapshot of my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "apollo-server": "^2.16.0",
    "apollo-server-express": "^2.16.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mysql2": "^2.1.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "sequelize": "^6.3.3",
    "sequelize-typescript": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bluebird": "^3.5.32",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.6",
    "@types/dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.7",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.0",
    "@types/node": "^14.0.23",
    "@types/sequelize": "^4.28.9",
    "@types/validator": "^13.1.0",
    "module-alias": "^2.2.2",
    "sequelize-cli": "^6.2.0",
    "ts-node-dev": "^1.0.0-pre.52",
    "tslint": "^6.1.2",
    "typescript": "^3.9.7"
  },
```

I can use the normal sequelize library but using the typescript version does not work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: try downgrading `sequelize` to `5.21.10`

Comment: @xMayank yes thanks it works. Does sequelize-typescript not work together with sequelize@6?

Comment: Yes till now it is not working lets see in future.